# How to simultaneously work with Spyder and PyCharm /Git

Tags: python, git, pycharm

Me and my friend are trying to code `Python` and we are both new with it. My friend has great `Java` and `OO` knowledge. He started the project but he is using `PyCharm` and `Git`. I also have PyCharm but sometimes it's hard to use it for me and I quite like the `Variable Explrorer` in Spyder. However, I could not import the project (which has several packages and classes) to Spyder without breaking the file structure.

The question is, is there any way we can both work simultaneously with PyCharm and Spyder and commit our changes to Git?

This is our file structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could work with Spyder and Git is by using the GiT GUI applications to manage changes and make commits. The issue is you may need to look for specific procedures to make PyCharm and GiT work together. Try the Spyder Help & Support working group, and maybe one of the coders there has figured it out.

Combination of these 3 apps:

- Spyder (anaconda3)
- GiT Bash
- Git GUI